# Greek San Symbol (ϻ)

Tags: fonts, greek

I'm desperatly trying to get my greek san symbol (ϻ; minusculus; http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=U%2B03fb) into my pdf.

Using

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1019}{\greeksansym}
{\fontfamily{dejavu}\selectfont \greeksansym}
```

didn't work. There is just a blank character in my pdf. Is there a Font for latex that includes the ϻ symbol?

Comment: don't know of any latex-supported font that includes this.  is it for text, or for use in math?

Comment: If you can use `xetex` or `luatex`, http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/03fa/fontsupport.htm shows fonts you could use.

Comment: There seems ti be an error in this page: the code for this glyph is U+03F`B`.

Comment: The glyph is in the `DejaVuSerif.pfb` but it is nowhere encoded. So one would have to generate tfm and other support files first before one can use it with pdflatex.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use LuaLaTex you just need a proper font. For the following example, place the font DejaVuSansMono.ttf in the same folder as your .tex file and compile with lualatex.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\unicodefont}[Extension = .ttf,  Ligatures=TeX]{DejaVuSansMono}
\begin{document}
\unicodefont{ϻ}
\end{document}
```